# Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand' in vb.net in oledb

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I am trying to run this command

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Sheet1$] AS A INNER JOIN [Orders$] IN'C:\Users\reddy\Desktop\Orders.xlsx' 'Excel 8.0;'
AS B
ON A.ContactName = B.ContactName;
```

but I am getting an error

> "Internal: Could not execute code stage because exception is thrown by
>   code stage: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been
>   initialized"

```
Dim oComm As New OleDbCommand 

        Dim oledbAdapter As new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL,moconnection)

        Dim oDataSet As New DataSet
                oledbAdapter.Fill(oDataSet)
                oledbAdapter.Dispose()
```

But I expected that Command should execute by that code

Comment: Have you set the .ConnectionString property of moconnection? Or passed to the constructor? If you keep your database objects local we could see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the join and I can't test it. When it comes to Excel, the .xlsx file is the database and each sheet is a table. I am hoping both Sheet1 and Orders are in the same file. If not you will need to approach this differently with 2 connections and a DataSet that can hold both DataTables where a relationship can be establish.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim strFileName As String = "C:\Users\reddy\Desktop\Orders.xlsx"
    Dim strCon As String = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={strFileName};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
    Using cn = New OleDbConnection(strCon)
        Dim sql = "Select * FROM [Sheet1$] As A INNER JOIN [Orders$] AS B On A.ContactName = B.ContactName;"
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```